# HTML Links not working within <ul> tag

Tags: html, css

I am working off a template to play around with codes and am having difficulty in getting the "Template Store" link to work.

Please can you help me solve this problem as nothing currently happens when clicked.

**Update:**

Here is a link to my website - http://www.graphixinc.co.za/test/index.html. I'm using `target  = _blank` here, but it isn't working.

**Here is the code:**

```
<div class="navigation">
        <img src="images/navigate.png" alt="navigate_img"/>
        <ul>  
            <li>  
                <a href="#take-me-home" class="nav-active rounded"><span>Take Me Home</span></a>  
            </li> 
            <li>  
                <a href="http://www.mywebsite.co.za/store" class="roundedss" target="blank"><span>Template Store</span></a>  
            </li> 
            <li>  
                <a href="#about" class="rounded"><span>About</span></a>  
            </li>  
            <li>  
                <a href="#services" class="rounded"><span>Services</span></a>    
            </li>  
            <li>  
                <a href="#showcase" class="rounded"><span>Portfolio</span></a>    
            </li>
            <li>  
                <a href="#our-team" class="rounded"><span>On Promo</span></a>    
            </li>   
            <li>  
                <a href="#news" class="rounded"><span>News</span></a>  
            </li> 
            <li>  
                <a href="#contact-us" class="rounded"><span>Contact Us</span></a>  
            </li>  

        </ul>  
    </div>
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: target should be "_blank" and i tested it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KRsxS/1/) and it works

Answer (score 1):

That's because `target="blank"` should be  `target="_blank"`

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.co.za/store" class="roundedss" target="_blank"><span>Template Store</span></a>
```

Comment: I thank you all for such speedy and prompt responses. I tried all suggestions on this page and it just isnt working.

Comment: @user2261249 What part of it is not 'working'? This definitely works, so there must be a problem with another part of your code. What's happening when you click on this link?

Comment: When i click the link in the browser, it does not do anything. If it helps, the template I am playing with is the Kronos Template from Themeforest and the way the links work in this templte is that it is one page and when you click a link, the page scrolls to a certain part of the same page.

Comment: @user2261249 So, you want this link to stay on the same page too? If so, the href will be like #store or #template wouldn't it? Instead of an external link? If not, try using _parent instead of _blank

Comment: I am not sure. There is a link entitled "Template Store" and the url to that is external. So when a person clicks "Template Store" i want them to be taken through the url in the code.

Comment: @user2261249 We can't help more than this unless we see more code that you're using, as this code works fine by itself. What's the name of your website?

Comment: I just right clicked now and opened the link in a new tab and it worked fine but not by clicking the link.. I have uploaded it to a location http://www.graphixinc.co.za/test/index.html   This is the Kronos web template

Comment: @user2261249 That is pretty weird! I will put the link in your question so we can get some more views on this.

Comment: Thanks. I take it you didnt find any problem?

Comment: @user2261249 Nope, but my guess is that as the template was meant to be used internally, there's some code somewhere that is causing this.

Comment: @user2261249 You may need to post more code related to the template you're using, as if this was just pure HTML, it would work. Your page seems like it's got some type of tab system implemented, so maybe the code relating to that

Comment: I am not sure which to post as there are so many files in this template. Do you have any suspicions as to what it MIGHT be?

Comment: Ok. Thank you to everyone for trying. I will just place the link elsewhere.

Comment: @user2261249 Hope you find your solution soon!

Answer (score 0):

target should be "_blank" and i tested it...

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.co.za/store" class="roundedss" target="_blank"><span>Template Store</span></a>
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/KRsxS/1/) is the fiddle for it, it works fine...

Comment: Thank you but i cannot view the link you guys are sending?

Comment: Hi Nikos, the page isn't uploaded yet. I am just working on my laptop at present.